# Populate a select box with a vocabulary

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, forms

I have a select box that I want to populate with a particular taxonomy programmatically. If i was was to use a taxonomy vocabulary how would i populate a particular select box in my form. My form is generated using the from api and not using content types. If for example I was to have a vocabulary called countries. I have a select box which currently is configured like this

```
 $form['status']['currentstatus'] = array (
 '#values' => array(t('red'), ('green'))


 );


$form['status']['currentStatusList'] = array (
    '#title' => 'current status',
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $form['status']['currentstatus']['#values']    
);
```

Instead of just adding the values I would like to pass a vocabulary.

I have manged to get the vocabulary data 
but a zero is placed before the terms.

[image]

the code I figured out for the box is the same as yours. I even pass the id for the vocabulary. I will have a play with it thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`taxonomy_get_tree`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7) function to get all the children of the term, and then just run a `foreach()` on that.

Example:

```
function mymodule_blah($vocabulary) {
  $terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary);

  foreach ($terms as $data) {
    $output[$data->tid] = $data->name;
  }

  return $output;
}
```

This should return an array keyed by Term ID, although you could put whatever you want where it says `$data['tid']` to put a different key in.

Example output:

```
[1] => ['My First Term']
[2] => ['My Second Term']
...
[15] => ['My Fifteenth Term']
```

Then pass this to your `'#options'` on your select box.

EDIT:

Forgot to mention that the helper function will need the vocabulary ID passed to it - should have added in the clarification just for completeness' sake.

EDIT 2 (full implementation):

```
function mymodule_myform($form) {
//The rest of your form stuff is in here
$form['status']['currentStatusList'] = array (
    '#title' => 'current status',
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => mymodule_selectbox_contents(PUT THE NUMERIC VOCABULARY ID HERE)    ,
);
//The rest of your form stuff is in here
}

function mymodule_selectbox_contents($vid) {
  $terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);

  foreach ($terms as $data) {
    $output[$data->tid] = $data->name;
  }

  return $output;
}
```

Comment: i think there is a problem with the syntax for the $output

Comment: I've edited the code, please try again :)

Comment: $output[$data->tid] => $data->'name'; My editor says there is a problem with the syntax. Is there anything that I am missing. I am using drupal 7 if that helps

Comment: D'oh, I forgot to remove the 's around name!  Just remove them and all should be fine!

Comment: i remove the single quotes around name but still get an error.  Am I missing other code i need

Comment: I'm not completely sure what else could be wrong to be honest.  I'll edit my answer with the entire implementation.

Comment: @Alexander I've just re-read my code and I realised I'd still screwed up.  I'm sorry man!  I've edited my answer and it all should work fine now.  I've also bought some coffee as I figure that was my problem yesterday :p

Comment: don't worry I really understand how the code works.  I have one question about passing the values though too the     options

Comment: ?  If you add it to the main question I'll add to my answer.  This comment thread is getting a bit long now =\

Answer (score 1):

See Chapabu's answer; if you want to make it more dynamic, you can use [taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load/7) to load the vocabulary id.

Here's a addition to Chapabu's implementation:

```
  function mymodule_myform($form) {
    //The rest of your form stuff is in here
    $voc = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load(your_machine_name);
    $form['status']['currentStatusList'] = array (
        '#title' => 'current status',
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => mymodule_selectbox_contents($voc->vid),
    );
    //The rest of your form stuff is in here
  }

    function mymodule_selectbox_contents($vid) {
      $terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);

      foreach ($terms as $data) {
        $output[$data->tid] = $data->name;
      }

      return $output;
  }
```